# why rabbitmq could not created v_host when installing using helm in kubenretes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am install RabbitMQ 3.8.0 in kubernetes v1.16.0 using helm like this:

```
./helm install report-mq --set prometheus.operator.enabled=false stable/rabbitmq-ha -n middleware
```

but when I logging in RabbitMQ's UI using `management` account, I could not created any v_host, something I am missing? what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It should setup the default vhost at `/` and the `guest` account is given access to that vhost. Check the logs of the pod

```
kubectl logs my-release-rabbitmq-ha-0

2020-06-05 13:25:01.400 [info] <0.268.0> Importing concurrently 1 permissions...
2020-06-05 13:25:01.400 [info] <0.511.0> Setting permissions for 'guest' in '/' to '.*', '.*', '.*'
```

So you need to login with the `guest` account and not the `management` account.